# merge arrays with shared element keeping other properties

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
  arr = [
         [ Date1, 1, null],
         [ Date1, null, 2],
         [ Date2, 1, null],
         [ Date2, null, 2],
         [ Date3, 1, null],
         [ Date3, null, 2],
         [ Date4, 2, null],
         [ Date5, 1, null] ];
```

It never has both nulls but can have only 1 value on a date, the expected is this:

```
    arr = [
    [ Date1, 1, 2],
    [ Date2, 1, 2],
    [ Date3, 1, 2],
    [ Date4, 2, null],
    [ Date5, 1, null] ];
```

Comment: Show us your attempt at this and we can help you.

Comment: Hint: create a temporary object that will use the date values as keys

Comment: Ok, just a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `reduce`. Just check if you already have an item with the same first element, and if so, combine them:

```js
const arr = [
  [ "Date1", 1, null],
  [ "Date1", null, 2],
  [ "Date2", 1, null],
  [ "Date2", null, 2],
  [ "Date3", 1, null],
  [ "Date3", null, 2],
  [ "Date4", 2, null],
  [ "Date5", 1, null],
];

const result = arr.reduce((combined, item) => {
  // Do we already have an item with the same first element?:
  const existingItem = combined.find(x => x[0] === item[0]);
  
  if (!existingItem) {
    // If not, just add the current item to the array
    combined.push(item);
  } else {
    // If so, go through the current item, and add any non-null elements to the existing item.
    item.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (element) existingItem[index] = element;
    });
  }
  return combined;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

EDIT: Some caveats:

In your snippet, i'm not sure what the type of your date objects are. The important thing is that they can be compared with `===`. If they can't, you'll have to replace the function in `find` with one that can properly check for equality for whatever type those dates are.

Second, the replacement of elements in the existing item (in the forEach block) is based on a simple truthyness check. But if some of your items will be valid but falsey (like the number `0`, for example), you'll want to replace the line `if (element) ...` with something like `if (element !== null) ...` instead, so that it will allow falsey but valid values though.

Basically, modify it to suit your use case in whatever way you need, just be aware of what this code is doing and where it might not be desirable.

Comment: Thanks, I used lodash ´ _.isEqual(x[0], item[0]) ´ to make it work. Tho it looks like I went for an easy exit it took me a while to make data look as the asked. Any advice/resource to get better at this? Tnx again!

Answer (score 1):

edit: i think CRices answer is better and more elegant.

I am not sure i understood, but something like this would work.

Maybe some Array.reduce call could work too...

```
var merged = [];

arr.forEach(function(value){
    var date = value[0];
    if (typeof date.extra1 === "undefined" || value[1] !== null) {
        date.extra1 = value[1];
    }
    if (typeof date.extra2 === "undefined" || value[2] !== null) {
        date.extra2 = value[2];
    }
    if (merged.indexOf(date) === -1) {
        mered.push(date);
    }
});

merged = merged.map(function(value){
    return [
        value,
        value.extra1,
        value.extra2
    ]
});
```